# How can I use HTML Agility Pack to retrieve all the images from a website?

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I just downloaded the HTMLAgilityPack and the documentation doesn't have any examples.

I'm looking for a way to download all the images from a website. The address strings, not the physical image.

```
<img src="blabalbalbal.jpeg" />
```

I need to pull the source of each img tag. I just want to get a feel for the library and what it can offer. Everyone said this was the best tool for the job.

**Edit**

```
public void GetAllImages()
    {
        WebClient x = new WebClient();
        string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.Load(source);

                         //I can't use the Descendants method. It doesn't appear.
        var ImageURLS = document.desc
                   .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                   .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));        
    }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ, like this:

```
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

**EDIT**: This code now actually works; I had forgotten to write `document.DocumentNode`.

Comment: What object type is document in your example? I can't use the .Descendants method. Please check my edit.

Comment: I forgot to include `.DocumentNode`.

Comment: also check you are using the latest beta as the linq functionality is new

Answer (score 10):

Based on their one example, but with modified XPath:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 List<string> image_links = new List<string>();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img"))
 {
    image_links.Add( link.GetAttributeValue("src", "") );
 }
```

I don't know this extension, so I'm not sure how to write out the array to somewhere else, but that will at least get you your data. (Also, I don't define the array correctly, I'm sure. Sorry).

## Edit

Using your example:

```
public void GetAllImages()
    {
        WebClient x = new WebClient();
        string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        List<string> image_links = new List<string>();
        document.Load(source);

        foreach(HtmlNode link in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img"))
        {
          image_links.Add( link.GetAttributeValue("src", "") );
       }


    }
```

Comment: Make that: `List<string> image_links = new List<string>();
                foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
                {
                  image_links.Add( link.GetAttributeValue("src", "")  );
                }`