# how to find a image tags in source code using C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am working with c# now stored webpage content in single variable and I have one text box if I paste any URL that will show the full source code the link .now I want to find all the image tags where it is begin and where it is finished.also I like to merge except image tags .

can you anyone tell me how to do..

Comment: I have removed ASP.NET, MVC and Classic ASP from the tags. This has nothing to do with any of those technologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use HTML Agility Pack to retrieve all the images from a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113924/how-can-i-use-html-agility-pack-to-retrieve-all-the-images-from-a-website)

Comment: I think he wants mark where the image tags start and where they end in the html text; the find part is duplicate but doesn't necessarily need to be HtmlAgilityPack, which, coincidentally, I would actually agree would be the best way of locating the tag. We should focus on answering the part where he asks how to find the beginning and end of the tags. Bit strange though as the `img` tag doesn't necessarily have a closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to parse the content server-side you can use the Html Agility pack

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113924/how-can-i-use-html-agility-pack-to-retrieve-all-the-images-from-a-website) question

Comment: just remember in the linked question the src of the image was located whereas your question here asks for the tags themself. Unless, when you say you want stored you mean to download the images as well as the html, in that case you would need both.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
if (images != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode image in images)
    {
        var alt = image.GetAttributeValue("alt", "");
        var nodeForReplace = HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(alt);
        image.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(nodeForReplace, image);
    }
}

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```