# Get a file url without webbrowser - C#

Tags: c#, string, dom

I'm trying to get the Url of an image, at the moment I have this code which does work but needs a webBrowser to do so.

```
    public void getFileUrl(HtmlDocument htmlDocument)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection htmlCollectionImage = htmlDocument.Images;
        foreach (HtmlElement htmlImage in htmlCollectionImage)
        {
            string Url = htmlImage.GetAttribute("src");
            if (Url.StartsWith("http://www.exemple.com/"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Url);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to peace something up which doesn't require the webBrowser, but I really don't know how to do that.

Also instead of an `HtmlDocument htmlDocument` being fed to the method, I need to feed it a simple `string`.

Any alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML code from a website C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-a-website-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var fileUrls = GetFileUrl(@"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054662/get-a-file-url-without-webbrowser-c-sharp", @"https://www.gravatar.com/");

    foreach (string url in fileUrls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetFileUrls(string url)
{
    var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
    var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                    .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                    .Where(s => s.ToLower().StartsWith(pattern));

    return urls;
}
```

Adapted from: [How can I use HTML Agility Pack to retrieve all the images from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113924/how-can-i-use-html-agility-pack-to-retrieve-all-the-images-from-a-website)

Edited to include usage and add a pattern parameter to GetFileUrls().

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I when I try to check the returned `urls.ToString()`, I get this : `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator 1[System.String]`

I tried to use the Url and still didn't work. I don't know if I did something wrong

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to use it. As it's returning a collection of the images (`IEnumerable<string>`), you can't just cast it to a string. You need to iterate through it and then you can work with each url. I also edited the method to add a second parameter, pattern, so you can specify what you want it to start with when you call the method - be careful with http/https though as it could give you some trouble, perhaps consider changing it to string.Contains() and omitting the protocol, or even RegEx.

Comment: Thanks got it to work, my problem was I was trying to check the `urls` from inside the `GetFileUrls()` instead of with `url` as you did.